# How to use axios/nodejs multipart/form to PUT a local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I'm trying to replicate is this CURL request (which works)

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url https://playcanvas.com/api/assets/ASSET_ID \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form file=@/Users/ilia/Development/playcanvas-rivalry/files/test.script.js \
  --form branchId=BRANCH_ID
```

But with nodejs/axios instead. Here's what I'm trying:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true })
const axios = require('axios')
const buildUrl = require('build-url')
const FormData = require('form-data')

router.put('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const url = buildUrl(process.env.BASE_URL, {
    path: `/projects/${process.env.PROJECT_ID}/assets/${req.params.id}`,
  })

  const { file_name } = req.query
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `../files/${file_name}`)
  
  try {
    // console.log('update asset by id');
    const formData = new FormData()
    // console.log('formData', formData);
    formData.append('branchId', req.query.branchId || process.env.BRANCH_ID)
    // console.log(formData);
    formData.append('file', fs.readFile(filePath))
    
    // console.log(url, formData);

    const update = await axios.put(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.TOKEN}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        // ...formData.getHeaders()
      },
    })
    console.log(update);
    res.send(update)
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error)
  }
})
```

I think the problem is with `fs.readFile`, I've also tried `fs.createReadStream` but nothing seems to work.

How can I replicate that curl request in nodejs + axios and send a local file?

Comment: Add fileName in this file key so that JS know you want to insert binary content. `formData.append('file', fs.readFile(filePath),fileName)`

Comment: @ilrein, Are you success with Anil's tips?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fs.createReadStream`, and also it should work without including headers:

```
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath))

//...

const update = await axios.put(url, formData, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.TOKEN}`
    },
})
```